# Writing htaccess that reroutes to other folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to write a rule that redirects a request to a different file/path. Here is a sample of the incoming URL: `/js/library/sample.js`, has to reroute to `/private/package/library/js/sample.js`.

I tried:

```
ReWriteCond ^/js/(A-Za-z_]+)$/(A-Za-z.]+)$ /private/package/$1/js/$2
```

I'm finding it difficult to write the rule correctly though.

Thanks.
PS. Any good htaccess/rejex tutorials, send them along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
RewriteRule ^(js)/([\w]+)/([\w.]+)/?$ /private/package/$2/$1/$3 [NC,L]
```

I found these Apache <sup>docs</sup> sufficient to learn.

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/

Comment: That worked nicely, however now all my requests to /js/ are directed. The rule should stop if there's a second path so /js/package/sample.js should trigger the rule, however /js/sample.js should not. That was also the tricky part. Excellent, those docs look helpful.

Comment: @user1213186 The rewrite rule is fine. Do you have any other rules along with the above?

Comment: I certainly do ThinkingMoney (but this darn comment box keeps killing my whitespacing, sorry):

    RewriteEngine on


    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @user1213186 The above rules should not affect the `RewriteRule` given in answer.

Comment: And yet it doesn't function as I hope. Oi veh. Thanks, for helping me out guys.